# Magento: Shopping Cart Price Rule Missing Options - What is going on?

Tags: e-commerce, magento-1.5, magento

I have two installs of Magento 1.5.1 and one of them has **all the options for Shopping Cart Price Rule** [image: all the options]

while the other one has a **reduced set of options**.[image: .]

**What could possibly be causing this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set individual attributes to have the ability to be included in catalogue price rules so one of your installs has different settings at an attribute level.

Go into Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes and for each attribute you want to be able to set a price rule on set `Use for Promo Rule Conditions` to Yes (its the bottom Front End properties section).

Comment: You beat me to it. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Like everything, obvious when you know about it. I once set up a whole raft of coupons with a crazy 1 product per category because I didn't realise you could add the SKU to the Promo Rule Conditions in this way.